# Errors Compiling xcode and FBSDK

Tags: xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine

When creating an assembly produces an error.

if through .cdworkspace

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKDeviceLoginCodeInfo._verificationURL in:
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hiyuaervseeqdjddnyzvacrngstr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FBSDKLoginKit/libFBSDKLoginKit.a(FBSDKDeviceLoginCodeInfo.o)
    /Users/admin/Desktop/ios_idle/Frameworks/FacebookSDK/Plugins/iOS/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKDeviceLoginCodeInfo.o)
ld: 1197 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

if through .xcodeproj

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-aznohbyfwguqcwgiyilrfrsrcddz/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-aznohbyfwguqcwgiyilrfrsrcddz/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FBSDKLoginKit'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-aznohbyfwguqcwgiyilrfrsrcddz/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit'
ld: library not found for -lBolts
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

how fix it?

Comment: I am experiencing an identical issue, I even have exactly 1197 duplicate symbols. I am using Unity 2018.4.9 LTS and Xcode 10.1. I have tried updating the Facebook SDK from 16.1 to 17.2 but it persists. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @Phedg1  The problem is not solved.

Comment: I finally just got this working, I've put my solution down below.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted everything in the FacebookSDK folder in my project except for the file FacebookSDK/SDK/Resources/FacebookSettings. I saved this file so I wouldn't have to re add my settings again later. Then I reimported the Facebook SDK.

It seems that the SDK has had some significant hierarchical changes in the recent versions. When updating to one of the newer versions it did not remove all of the redundant files properly, leading to duplicate classes across across the different versions.